# Python method using multiple same kwargs

Tags: python

Is there a way to have a python funciton/method accept multiple `kwargs` that are the same key?

Example:

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    print kwargs['a']

foo(a=1, a=2)
[1, 2]
```

Or something along the lines of that.

I know `kwargs` wouldn't be a standard dictionary at that point. I have a feeling I already know the answer to this but figured I ask if black magic existed in meta classes somewhere.

I'm trying to mimic another language as close as possible.  TitanDB has a query language ontop of gremlin and in gremlin the methods accept keyword args that repeat

```
g.v(256).outE(label='knows', label='likes').inV
```

I would like to stay as close to this as possible.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you explain the problem you might find a simpler approach.

Comment: Yes, why would you do this, rather than `a=[1,2]`? Are you trying to pass or inherit some kwargs from a class hierarchy or default or something? You really need to step back from the code and describe what you're trying to do.

Comment: You really ought to try to avoid the "mimic another language" pardagim. Python is Python, C is C, C++ is a living hell, and ne'r the twain shall meet. Python has the patterns and syntax it has for a reason; trying to force another set of pardagims and patterns on it is just... not wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. There is no metaclass magic to be had because this syntax is illegal in Python.

What do you want to get when you get the value of label anyway?
If you want to get a list or tuple of items, just pass a list/tuple, ie label=("knows","likes").